# fdtd ansys Lumerical vs fresnel solution

Tags: finite-difference, computational-physics

I am comparing reflectance intensity of silicon structure with a hole. I am getting oscillating solution for 0 roughness factor in equation based model. but spectrum shape of fdtd and equation based model solution starts matching if i increase the roughness factor. does this mean there is some default roughness factor in fdtd Lumerical solution?
thanks
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXJZJ.jpg)
[image]
[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. lumerical is software for fdtd. i got one result from that software.